# Sudden DNS Problems With Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: dns, systemd, systemd-resolved

I have suddenly been having DNS resolution problems with my Ubuntu 18.10 server. I checked everything, /etc/netplan etc, couldnt see anything that had changed. Tried rebooting several times.

I get:
ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

UFW firewall is inactive.

The problem first occurred yesterday. Then several hours later suddenly disappeared. Now this morning it is back again.

The only thing I can think of is that it occurred after I did an apt update & apt upgrade yesterday. Before then it was ok.

I have heard there may be a bug in systemd-resolved which causes this behaviour but I don't know for certain. Perhaps an upgrade of systemd or resolved is responsible. Because nothing has changed in my configuration files.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem or know what the cause is and what I could do about it?

Comment: FWIW I upgraded to 19.04 on Friday and had the same problems for a while, maybe 10 minutes after reboot. They went away of themselves and haven't come back.

Comment: I did a: 
"service systemd-resolved restart"  and the DNS started working again. So presumably there is a problem with this service.